# Passing POST parameters - no URL. Where are they exactly?

Tags: post, client, idempotent

I'm designing a simple web appliance that takes temperature and humidity readings and I want to post them to a remote server and have them added to a MySQL table of data.

I understand that GET is the wrong way to do this because of the idempotency problem.  However, what is the syntax or method for doing this with a POST if you can't just cobble up a URL and call the page with it?

I'm working at a fairly low level on the client side - a microprocessor with an Ethernet library.  It has a client.open() interface, and then I can send "print" statements to the open client connection.

### Does anyone know what the server is supposed to see to receive a post and a bunch of arguments?

K